# Ideas for time series gap-filling (using statistical learning?)

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, time-series, imputation

I am looking for some input for a time series problem.

What I have is land use data from 2008-2018.
Each row looks something like this, where every value stands for the land use of a certain cell at a consecutive year:

```
[1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0]
```

Each number stands for a land use type.

However sometimes it looks like this:

```
[1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, NaN, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0]
```

And sometimes it looks like this:

```
[1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 8.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0]
```

Class 3.0 = Dense forest,
Class 8.0 = Built-up Area

Both in the case of NaN and inconsistent land use transitions I would like to use something like statistical learning to fill and correct my observations with a land use type that is likely to occur based on previous and past land use.

Right now, I have build a scoring scheme, where the previous land use and past land use use types are scored (the closer to the missing the heavier the weight). The land use type with the highest score is then filled in for the missing/inconsistent value. I am still figuring out how to test the performance of this scheme.

In any case, the scoring scheme is a bit arbitrary, I would like to have some input for other ideas I could try. I am pretty ok with python, but still a beginner with Machine Learning and imputations.

Thanks a lot for your ideas!

Answer (score 2):

The best method may not be to use statistical learning

- Impute with last value
- Impute with average between last and following non missing value
- Impute with average in rolling windows

Or you can try some linear regression or time-series based modeling (arima, LSTM, ...) but again;, I am not sure it is the best methods. You should try and evaluate result empirically.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions thibaultbl! 
Imputing based on averages will not work well since these are discrete classes. Imputing based on the last value is possible but this does not make much use of the available data and the common patterns seen in the data set regarding land use changes. Perhaps the initial scoring scheme is not a bad idea after all. I will try to test its performance by purposely leaving out data where actually data exists and see how accurately it predicts versus imputation done solely based on previous or next year.

Comment: If it is discrete class, you may Impute with just another new value that will act as a dummy for missing value indicator.